# File attachment is not opening-Not Allowed Error

Tags: javascript

This is my first attempt to prepare a dynamic pdf form in livecycle designer es4. In this form, there is an option to add and view attachment. As I have little experience in javascript coding, I went to the adobe forum and found a very good example [here](https://forums.adobe.com/thread/2517255). I have done some changes in original code to run in my form. I can attach file successfully with this code. But my problem is that when I want to open file attachment in Acrobat Pro XI, it is showing below error instead of opening the file. This error is showing independent of file attachment type (e.g. .doc, .jpg, .txt and .pdf file).[error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sy0cd.png). Here is screenshot of security of Acrobat Pro XI[screenshot 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i0Fkn.png) [screenshot 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rLS7F.png) and file link[here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1TKHHl-xQgjefzDIV4GD9BmQfFAN0rPWo/view?usp=sharing).
Below code is written in the form-

```
//Code for add button
// Get Import Name
var cName = AttachName.rawValue;
// Test for empty value
if(!/^\s*$/.test(cName))
{// Do Import
   try{
     var bRtn = event.target.importDataObject(cName);
     if(bRtn)
     {
        var cDesc = AttachDesc.rawValue;
        if(!/^\s*$/.test(cName))
        {
            var oAtt = event.target.getDataObject(cName);
            oAtt.description = cDesc;
        }
        app.alert("File Attachment Successfully Imported",3);
     }
     else
        app.alert("Unable to import File Attachment",0);
   }catch(e){
     app.alert("An Error Occured while Importing the File Attachment:\n\n" + e);
   }
}
else
   app.alert("Attachment name must be non-empty");

//code for populating dropdown list
this.rawValue = null;
this.clearItems();
var a = event.target.dataObjects;
if (a !== null) {
for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
this.addItem(a[i].name); 
}
}

//code for open attachment button
var cName = AttachNameSel.rawValue;
//var nAction = ExportAction.rawValue;
    try{
    event.target.exportDataObject({cName:cName, nLaunch:2});
    } catch(e) {
      app.alert("An Error Occured while Exporting the File Attachment: " + cName + "\n\n" + e);
    }
```

Any help from anyone in the community would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Tony